# Google App Engine routing problem

Tags: support, google-app-engine

I'm experiencing random timeouts to  <strike>some Api endpoints (Fitness, Drupal).</strike>  all the API endpoints from Google App Engine.

You can check this odd behavior using these links:

http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted?service=drupal.stackexchange&tagged=&page=3&pagesize=30
http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted?service=fitness.stackexchange&tagged=&page=3&pagesize=30
http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted?service=stackoverflow&tagged=&page=3&pagesize=30

All the Stack Exchange app[s] hosted on Google App Engine should be affected by the same problem.

Please star [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4718) issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've looked into this, and there's literally nothing different between api.drupal and api.stackoverflow.

Without more to go on, we're forced to assume this is a GAE problem.

Comment: are you confirming that, when stackprinter gets a timeout, you are not seeing any calls to your end?

Comment: @systempuntoout - its hard to correlate a failing call on a server I don't control with any showing up in our logs.  However, I can confirm that nothing that's gotten to the API from StackPrinter in the last few days has taken longer than 343 milliseconds (that's max, typical is in the 30-40 range).

Comment: finally fixed :)

Comment: Who or what is "GAE"? And what was "the" fix?

Comment: GAE stands for Google App Engine